# Text moving in animated frames

Tags: beamer, animations

I am not sure why I am seeing this behaviour, but when I compile the following code, on the second frame, the first line is moved down. I have `\begin{frame}[t]` so supposedly this should not happen, but it does. My slide is more complicated with tikz figures, but this MWE also demonstrates my problem. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[table,dvipsnames,aspectratio=149,11.5pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
    \frametitle{Two Examples}
    
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item GraphPartition 
            \only<1>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Data is partitioned using METIS
                    \item Replicate vertices using \emph{n-hop guarantee}
                    \item If the radius of $Q$ is not larger than $n$, $Q$ can be locally evaluated in each site 
                    \item If the radius of $Q$ is larger than $n$, $Q$ is decomposed into several subqueries $Q_i$ that can be independently evaluated; then their results are joined 
                \end{itemize}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \item Shape 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Generate triple groups based on common subject or object
                    \item Semantic hashing triple groups 
                    \item Allow some data replication between different partitions
                \end{itemize}
            }
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
        \centering
        \only<1>{
                \centering
                \begin{pgfpicture}
                    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=5cm,height=3cm]{scratch1.png}}
                \end{pgfpicture}
        }
        \only<2>{
                \centering
                \begin{pgfpicture}
                    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=5cm,height=2cm]{scratch1.png}}
                \end{pgfpicture}
                \vskip0.5cm
                
                \centering
                \begin{pgfpicture}
                    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=5cm,height=2cm]{scratch2.png}}
                \end{pgfpicture}
        }
   \end{column} 
\end{columns}
        
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{columns}` is doing its own vertical alignment. Use `\begin{columns}[T]` instead. (Exercise: try also `\begin{columns}[t]`)

Comment: Yes, that was it. Many thanks; I should have thought of this but I didn't. Much appreciated.